# rethinkdb & nodejs: save result in var

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

it's possible save result query of rethinkdb in a variable?

Like this??

```
var test = r.db('chat').table('group_chat').count(r.row('passengers').contains(function(passeggers) {
   return passeggers('nome').eq('pigi');
 })).run()
```

now I use this method

```
var test;

r.db('chat').table('group_chat').count(r.row('passengers').contains(function(passeggers) {
   return passeggers('nome').eq('pigi');
 })).run().then(function(response){
    test = response;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using promises and are using the latest version of ECMAScript, you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which provides syntactic sugar to let you write your asynchronous code as if it were synchronous.

You could rewrite your example like this:

```
async function getTest() {
    var test = await r.db('chat').table('group_chat').count(r.row('passengers').contains(function(passeggers) {
        return passeggers('nome').eq('pigi');
    })).run();
    return test;
}
```

Note that “behind the scenes”, this still uses promises, but it makes the code easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest yet working solution would be as bellow, using callback

```
function getTest(callback) { // add callback
    r.db('chat')
     .table('group_chat')
     .count(r.row('passengers')) // you forgot closing brace here
     .contains(function(passeggers) { 
       return passeggers('nome').eq('pigi') 
     })
     .run()
     .then(function(result) {
       callback(null, result); // call callback with result
     })
     .error(function(err) {
       callback(err, null);  // call callback with error
     });
}

getTest(function(err, result) { // invoke callback
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result)
  var test = result; // note: you can use test variable only inside this call
})
```